# Doesn't retrieve the records while viewing a ResultSet in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset, data-retrieval

Now i m learning ResultSet types in java. Here, I've coded for viewing records in different ways. At first i displayed the whole records which is in emp4 table and then i started to view these records in different manner(last,first,next) This is exactly what i am looking for but it won't display the all records which are presented in the emp4 table. See the First Program it doesn't work but if i documented the line 41(see this in Second Program) it just working awesome. What's the problem ? is there any wrong with my code ???

**CODE SAMPLE 1**

```
package demojdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MysqlCon{

private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vinoth";
private static final String DB_USER = "root";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "vino";

    public static void main(String args[])throws SQLException{

        //Creating statement and connection 
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try{

            //Creating class driver
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

            //Creating Database Connection
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

            //Creating statement
            stmt = dbConnection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            //Creating query
            String sql = "SELECT id,gmail,yahoo from emp4";

            //Creating ResultSet
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            //Displaying database
            System.out.println("Displaying records before doing some operations");
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));

            System.out.println("Displaying records for last row");
            rs.last();

            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String gmail = rs.getString("gmail");
            String yahoo = rs.getString("yahoo");

            //Displaying records in last row
            System.out.println("ID : "+id);
            System.out.println("GMAIL : "+gmail);
            System.out.println("YAHOO : "+yahoo);

            System.out.println();
            rs.first();
            System.out.println("Displaying records for first row");

            id = rs.getInt("id");
            gmail = rs.getString("gmail");
            yahoo = rs.getString("yahoo");

            //Displaying records in last row
            System.out.println("ID : "+id);
            System.out.println("GMAIL : "+gmail);
            System.out.println("YAHOO : "+yahoo);

            System.out.println();
            rs.next();
            System.out.println("Displaying records for next row");

            id = rs.getInt("id");
            gmail = rs.getString("gmail");
            yahoo = rs.getString("yahoo");

            //Displaying records in last row
            System.out.println("ID : "+id);
            System.out.println("GMAIL : "+gmail);
            System.out.println("YAHOO : "+yahoo);

        }catch(SQLException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

             System.out.println("Plese check the driver class path "+e.getMessage());

        }finally{

            if(stmt != null){

                stmt.close();

            }
            if(dbConnection != null){

                dbConnection.close();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the code will works fine.....

**CODE SAMPLE 2**

```
package demojdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MysqlCon{

private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vinoth";
private static final String DB_USER = "root";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "vino";

    public static void main(String args[])throws SQLException{

        //Creating statement and connection 
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try{

            //Creating class driver
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

            //Creating Database Connection
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

            //Creating statement
            stmt = dbConnection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            //Creating query
            String sql = "SELECT id,gmail,yahoo from emp4";

            //Creating ResultSet
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            //Displaying database
            System.out.println("Displaying records before doing some operations");
           //System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));

            System.out.println("Displaying records for last row");
            rs.last();

            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String gmail = rs.getString("gmail");
            String yahoo = rs.getString("yahoo");

            //Displaying records in last row
            System.out.println("ID : "+id);
            System.out.println("GMAIL : "+gmail);
            System.out.println("YAHOO : "+yahoo);

            System.out.println();
            rs.first();
            System.out.println("Displaying records for first row");

            id = rs.getInt("id");
            gmail = rs.getString("gmail");
            yahoo = rs.getString("yahoo");

            //Displaying records in last row
            System.out.println("ID : "+id);
            System.out.println("GMAIL : "+gmail);
            System.out.println("YAHOO : "+yahoo);

            System.out.println();
            rs.next();
            System.out.println("Displaying records for next row");

            id = rs.getInt("id");
            gmail = rs.getString("gmail");
            yahoo = rs.getString("yahoo");

            //Displaying records in last row
            System.out.println("ID : "+id);
            System.out.println("GMAIL : "+gmail);
            System.out.println("YAHOO : "+yahoo);

        }catch(SQLException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

             System.out.println("Plese check the driver class path "+e.getMessage());

        }finally{

            if(stmt != null){

                stmt.close();

            }
            if(dbConnection != null){

                dbConnection.close();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

Displaying records for last row
ID : 5
GMAIL : naveen
YAHOO : naveenrockz

Displaying records for first row
ID : 1
GMAIL : vinothvino
YAHOO : vinothasd

Displaying records for next row
ID : 2
GMAIL : ajithvirje
YAHOO : ajith234

*Please make me understand. Why my code doesn't fetch any records in the CODE SAMPLE 1 Program ?*

Below image represents the following records in emp4 table

[image]

Comment: How about showing us a stack trace or output from the first code which does not run correctly?

Comment: Yes it doesn't working. It just shows an exception like this "java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set" but if i comment the line 41 then it works without any problem... But i want to extract those data and want to display it before going to perform operations(last,first,next)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you haven't progressed the cursor of the `ResultSet` by calling [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) before accessing the data with `getInt()` / `getString()`. Try something like this instead:

```
//Creating ResultSet
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

//Displaying database
System.out.println("Displaying records before doing some operations");

if (rs.next()) {        
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " "
        + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3));
}
```

If you want to loop through the whole result set, use `while (rs.next())` instead.

Your second code snippet works because you are moving the cursor to the last position with [`rs.last()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#last%28%29) before accessing the column values for the first time.

Please note that you should always inspect the return value of `rs.next()` / `rs.last()` / `rs.first()` methods before accessing the column values. A falsey return value indicates that the result set has no rows and would cause an exception to be thrown when calling any of the getter (`rs.getInt()` / `rs.getString()` etc.) methods of the result set.

Comment: Thank you so much..... It really works fine,this is what i'm expecting now it comes without any issue but I've doubt ?
Why it doesn't work in with that line which i've posted but it works only with while or if ?  why? Both are same only know ? or not ?

Comment: I've edited the question to explain why your second code sample is working. Basically, any invocation to the `getX` methods of `ResultSet` need to be preceded with a method that moves the cursor.

Comment: This helps me alot.Thanks again for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

you need to use .next() function to jump into the first record in the result set

```
while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts...